# Socket.io server dropping connections

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I am working on a chat application (using NodeJS + Socket.IO).

In my server I have an array variable called *users* that stores all online users.

When user logs in, an object containing all user info is pushed into *users* array and, when it logs out, a '*user_logout*' event is emitted:

```html
var users = []; //array of online users

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  socket.on('user_login',(user)=>{
  //USER LOGS IN
    users.push(user)
  })
  socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
    //USER LOGS OUT
    var message = socket.id + "logs out"; // ERROR: socket is undefined
    io.emit('user_logout',message)
  })
})
```

As you can see from my snippet above, *socket* object seems to be undefined, causing my app to crash.

The error is thrown only if the user has been inactive for a while (let's say few minutes), otherwise it works perfectly !

It seems socket destroys the idle connections without warning, causing the object *socket* to be null

Comment: `socket.emit` will emit to the current socket which is disconnecting, you need `socket.broadcast.emit` instead, additionally your not removing the disconnected user from the users array

Comment: To be clear, when a `socket`  disconnects, you want to send a new message to that *same* socket, that won't receive it, because it's disconnected? One way around it would be to simply store the `id` so you don't need to go through the `socket` object

Comment: I accidentally write socket.emit instead of io.emit. Anyway the problem is always the same, socket is an undefined object

Comment: I never faced this. But try using `this` instead of socket

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `socket` being `undefined` on `disconnect` is a bug here - the socket is no longer connected, so no longer exists. I guess it would depend on when socket.io officially nulls the reference.

I couldn't find much in the documentation (https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99), but I suspect it's the difference between the server manually calling `disconnect()` and the socket getting disconnected because of a dropped connection, or similar.

Either stock the `id` separately, or you might try the `disconnecting` callback instead:

> Fired when the client is going to be disconnected (but hasn’t left its rooms yet).